# Simplify substituting variables in string with Golang

Tags: go, substitution

I'm trying to learn about the **Golang** language

Today I have a question about **substituting variables in string** with Golang

I've searched how to resolve it in golang and found **2 ways** as this [blog](https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-interpolating-or-substituting-variables-in-string-examples).

#### First way

The first way is using **`fmt.Sprintf`**, example (I've made one on [Go Playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/QvZhe45ROhP)):

```
msg := fmt.Sprintf("Hello %s, you have %d new messages", "Alice", 15)
fmt.Println(msg)
```

#### Second way

And the second one is using **`text/template`** package, example (I've made one on [Go Playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/0vufNgqzNyy)):

```
msg := "Hi {{.DisplayName}}, you have {{ .NumMessages }} new messages"

data := map[string]interface{}{
    "DisplayName": "Bob",
    "NumMessages": 15,
}

tmpl, err := template.New("msg").Parse(msg)
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err = tmpl.Execute(buf, data); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
s := buf.String()

fmt.Println(s)
```

I noticed that the first way is simple but it's **not easy to read**, and the second is **very complicated** (perhaps we need to create a utility function)

I've worked with **JavaScript** and I found that it's very simple:

```js
displayName = "Trudy"
numMessages = 15
msg = `Hello ${displayName}, you have ${numMessages} new messages`
console.log(msg)
```

Is there any way we can simplify this in Golang? Because I have just learned this language so I hope to have many ideas to improve my experience.

**Edit to reopen question**

My hope is whether there is a similar way in Golang such as JavaScript, it is also different with the above ways with the problems I mentioned (it shouldn't use placeholder for variable as first way, not easy to read, and it is also not complicated as second)

**Edit to close this question**

After a while of searching, I think Golang doesn't have a simple way to avoid this problem as JavaScript. Therefore I've closed this question without any other questions.

Comment: There's no way of interpolating variables to a Go string. However you can look at strings.Replacer

Comment: Answers to the marked duplicate list your best options with the standard library.